# Custom Rounding Rule

Tags: excel-formula

I have a simple spreadsheet like:

```
Column A
500
600
700
800
1000
```

and a corresponding

```
Column B (which is calculated by dividing Column A by 82)
6.097560976
7.317073171
8.536585366
9.756097561
12.19512195
```

Now I want to round up to the nearest whole number which I know how to do but only if the ending decimal is 0.3 or higher (else it should round down)

I want my results to look like this:

```
6
8
9
10
12
```

What is the best way to go about this

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use a formula such as `=IF(B2-TRUNC(B2)>=0.3,ROUNDUP(B2,0),ROUNDDOWN(B2,0))` in C2 to do a custom round (based on how the data is structured in your worksheet).

```
Column A    Column B (which is calculated by dividing Column A by 82)   Round Formula
500         6.097560976                                                   6
600         7.317073171                                                   8
700         8.536585366                                                   9
800         9.756097561                                                   10
1000        12.19512195                                                   12
```

`B2-TRUNC(B2)` extracts only the decimal portion of the number in column B, which is can then be compared against the threshold of 0.3 to decide if it should be rounded up or down.